# Serial communication with bytes (0x00 problem)

Tags: python, c, stm32, pyserial, cdc

I have a problem while using serial communication for USB CDC.
I'm working on embedded STM microcontrollers and i wanted to pass binary data with pySerial.

I wanted to send binary codes directly but I am blocked by this 0x00 ..
My problem is when i want to send 0x00 byte, the next bytes seems to be ignored..

Here's the python script:

```
towrite = [ 0xFF, 0xx00 \xFF ] 
nbSend = s.write(b'\xFF\x00\xFF')
print(nbSend)                                 #Displaying 3 here, that means 3 bytes are successfully sended
```

Then the embedded script:

```
//Interrupt function that receive the data from serial com
static int8_t CDC_Receive_FS(uint8_t* Buf, uint32_t *Len)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  USBD_CDC_SetRxBuffer(&hUsbDeviceFS, &Buf[0]);
  USBD_CDC_ReceivePacket(&hUsbDeviceFS);

  char buffer[64];

  sprintf(buffer,"Length=%lu / Word=%c%c%c ",(unsigned long)*Len,Buf[0],Buf[1],Buf[2]);
  debugPrintln(&huart2, buffer)  //Function to print on serial to debug
  //Here that print "Length=3 / Word=ÿ "


  return (USBD_OK);
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
```

As you can see, the second and ultimate characters (0x00, 0xFF) are not taken into account even if the number of bytes received is good ...
Any advice?

Comment: The null character terminates the string.  Nothing after that is usable to `sprintf`

Comment: Do not use a print function that expects _strings_, when attempting to print characters will a null byte.

Comment: Looks like your UART data is binary. `%c` won't print it too well (e.g. there's no viewable/printable ASCII char for that for 0x00 or 0xFF). How about (e.g.): `"Length=%lu / Word=%2.2X,%2.2X,%2.2X "`?

Answer (score 0):

It's the debugging that's not working, but the data transfer is just fine.

```
sprintf(buffer,"Length=%lu / Word=%c%c%c ",(unsigned long)*Len,Buf[0],Buf[1],Buf[2]);
```

The second `%c` puts an actual NUL byte in the buffer, so everything else after it is ignored by the `debugPrintln`.

For testing, change to:

```
sprintf(buffer,"Length=%lu / Word=%02X %02X %02X",(unsigned long)*Len,Buf[0],Buf[1],Buf[2]);
```

and see if it shows you all the bytes.